# How to count documents with query in ReactiveMongo with Play's JSON library?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Let's consider I have a collection `users` that have the `age` attribute. Now I want to count either all documents in the collection `users` or only the ones which match the `age` attribute. So, I did the following:

```scala
  def count(age: Option[Int] = None) = {
    if (age.isEmpty) roles.count()
    else users.count(Json.obj("age" -> age))
  }
```

The problem is that `users.count(Json.obj("age" -> age))` throws a compile error because the method `count` provided by reactive mongo expects the type `Option[pack.Document]`. Any idea how I can fix this?

I am using Reactive Mongo version 0.11.11 if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said, it expects an `Option` of `pack.Document`, aka `BSONDocument` when `pack` is the BSON serialization one, or `JsObject` when [using Play JSON](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html).

```
users.count(Some(Json.obj("age" -> age)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot believe that I missed that.

Comment: This approach is deprecated.

Comment: Nope, just there is a new/improved `.count`